# Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView

Tags: android, textview, android-appcompat, android-vectordrawable

I'm developing a simple example for Vector Drawable. I used the backward compatible library `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1` for pre-Lollipop device support.

The views used in the layout are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.nm.vectordrawableexample.VectorActivity">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/ic_logo"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_light_bulb" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Tap on icon to change tint color" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/ic_android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_flight_takeoff"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="TextView with Vector Drawable" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Radio button with vector drawable icons" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:showDividers="middle"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/radio_selector"
            android:button="@android:color/transparent" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioBtn2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/radio_selector"
            android:button="@android:color/transparent" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioBtn3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/radio_selector"
            android:button="@android:color/transparent" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioBtn4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/radio_selector"
            android:button="@android:color/transparent" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioBtn5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/radio_selector"
            android:button="@android:color/transparent" />

    </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the code snippet for the activity on which a click on the ImageView changes the color of the image used in the ImageView:

```
public class VectorActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static {
        AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_vector);
        final AppCompatImageView icAndroid= (AppCompatImageView) findViewById(R.id.ic_android);
        icAndroid.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_android);
        icAndroid.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Random random=new Random();
                int color= Color.argb(255,random.nextInt(256),random.nextInt(256),random.nextInt(256));
                icAndroid.setColorFilter(color);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the style file content description:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Now the question while executing the example on a device with Android 5.0+ (device description given below)

- ASUS Zenfone Max (Android Version 6.0).
- GenyMotion Emulator (Samsung Galaxy S7 Android Version 6.0 API 23)

The example executes successfully and shows the result also.
But while executing the same example on this device:

- GenyMotion Emulator HTC One 4.4.4 API 19 (480dpi)

It shows a Runtime Exception and the application stopped.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.nm.vectordrawableexample, PID: 1351
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nm.vectordrawableexample/com.nm.vectordrawableexample.VectorActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #38: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #38: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:288)
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
     at com.nm.vectordrawableexample.VectorActivity.onCreate(VectorActivity.java:21)
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:288) 
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
     at com.nm.vectordrawableexample.VectorActivity.onCreate(VectorActivity.java:21) 
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
  Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_flight_takeoff.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020055
     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2096)
     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
     at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:806)
     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:62)
     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:58)
     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:288) 
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
     at com.nm.vectordrawableexample.VectorActivity.onCreate(VectorActivity.java:21) 
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
  Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #1: invalid drawable tag vector
     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:933)
     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:877)
     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2092)
     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602) 
     at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:806) 
     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:62) 
     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:58) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:288) 
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
     at com.nm.vectordrawableexample.VectorActivity.onCreate(VectorActivity.java:21) 
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

app/build.gradle file content description

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.nm.vectordrawableexample"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

What section in the code went wrong? What changes are required to run the example successfully?

Comment: Please post app/build.gradle as well

Comment: try using this in gradle:`compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+"`

Comment: sorry didn't find any problem while running on Nexus 5 (Android 6.0.1)

Comment: Hi, @MCZ as mention in the question there is no problem while testing the  following with device 6.0

Comment: Post the drawable/ic_flight_takeoff.xml file

Comment: @blackjack I have the same issue, has occurred only on a samsung device running os 4. Did you find a fix?

Answer (score 1):

add below lines to your activity

```
static {
        AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an old problem, so maybe the author did not wait for an answer. But the problem is in the `res/drawable/ic_flight_takeoff.xml` file.

It is a vector drawable object that causes the error and if  add the following line in the build.gradle file `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` the error will dissapear.

In this case the vector drawable will not correctly convert to a `PNG` and is used as it is. If the drawable object is not convertet correctly the application will cause a crash on android versions prior to 5.0 (LOLLIPOP).

Answer (score 0):

API 19 and below seem to have difficulties with vector drawables. So instead of declaring a drawableLeft for your textView in XML, you can do it programmatically;

1. Create a `VectorDrawableCompat` 
   like:

   `Drawable drawable = VectorDrawableCompat.create(context.getResources(), R.drawable.your_drawable, null);`
2. Set the drawable to your textView as a drawableLeft like:

   `your_textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(drawable, null, null, null)`